# PHP file_get_contents() is ignoring the request body when making a GET request

Tags: php, database, http, elasticsearch

I am trying to make a simple HTTP GET request to query Elasticsearch. The Elasticsearch syntax allow the use of a request body in a GET request to add addition query options. I am using the PHP function **file_get_contents()** to make the GET request.

The problem is that file_get_contents() seems to be ignoring the body of the request when making a GET request yet it works fine when using a POST request instead.

How can I get **file_get_contents()** to process the body of the **GET** request correctly?
The code I am using is shown below.

Note that :

- I want to use **file_get_contents()** to do this, **NOT** php **cURL**, php **Request2**, or the **elasticsearch-php** library
- I would like to keep this as a **GET** request, changing it to a POST request instead is not what I am after

Thanks in advance!

```
$url = "example-elasticsearch-url-here.com/index/_search";
$body=<<<EOD
  {
    "_source": ["email"],
    "size":10,
    "query":{
       "match_all" : {}
    }
  }
  EOD;

$contextData = array (
                      'method' => 'GET',
                      'header' => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n".
                      'ssl'=>array(
                             "verify_peer"=>false,
                             "verify_peer_name"=>false,
                             ),
                      'content'=> $body
                      );

$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'https' => $contextData ));
try {
     $result =  file_get_contents ($url,false,$context);
} catch (Exception $e) {
     $result = false;
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work, if you use `http` instead of `https` as key name in `$context`?

Comment: No my elasticsearch is using https

Comment: I know, but as far is I know, the key name needs to be kept at `http`, no matter if http or https is used.

Comment: Thanks! that worked.. I feel silly now hehe.. simple fix. I will accept your answer shortly, thanks a lot!